# Getting error when sending email using sendgrid

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have created an azure function to send email using sendgrid but get the below error.

> The 'Function1' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Unable to resolve the value for property 'SendGridAttribute.ApiKey'. Make sure the setting exists and has a valid value

I took the sample from [Azure Functions SendGrid bindings - asynchronous](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid.md#asynchronous)

Given in the local.settings.json like below:

```json
{ 
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": 
  {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true", 
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet", 
    "AzureWebJobsServiceBus": " ..." 
    //"AzureWebJobsSendGridApiKey": "..." 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the setting for the SendGrid API key with the name specified in the attribute. Looking at the example you linked to, the name of the setting used there is `CustomSendGridKeyAppSettingName`. The platform uses the name used in the attribute to get the value for the SendGrid binding.

Also, the `AzureWebJobsSendGridApiKey` setting in your local.settings.json file is commented out, meaning it is non-existent as far as your Function goes.

If we use the name of the setting as used in the example, your local.settings.json file should look something like this:

```json
{ 
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": 
  {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true", 
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet", 
    "AzureWebJobsServiceBus": " ..." 
    "AzureWebJobsSendGridApiKey": "<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>"
  }
}
```

Comment: I just followed the documentation and did accordingly to what the documentation. but did not work.